# I want to group by month how to do?in django

Tags: linux, django

sumary = Profile.objects.values('user_report__created_date__month')

Error
Cannot resolve keyword 'month' into field. Join on 'created_date' not permitted.

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Имя'))
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Department(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='user_report')
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='report')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    edited_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.department.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Отчет')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Отчеты')


class Statistic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, related_name='stat_report')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: We are supposed to read your mind and answer this without your models?

Comment: Without seeing you models, we can't see the relations and fields - so we can't be of much help. Edit your post and add those in + whatever you've tried so far. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
end_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=31)
start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
summary = Profile.objects.filter(user_report__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

This is to get the user reports from one month. Is that correct? Please add more code if you want a more accurate answer.

Comment: no i want to do in value not filter i want to group on month by value

Comment: For example let's say I have a 2-year report, I want to share this report on months

Comment: You can change the values end_date and start_date to get reports based on how long you want them. I am not sure if I fully understand your question.

Comment: so sumary = Profile.objects.values ​​( 'user_report__created_date__month') it can be done? through objects.value, i want to filter with objects.value

Comment: I still don't get what you want, but what you posted is not going to work.  When you filter you get the values from the records. You just have to 'extract' them from the record. Like this: `summary.0.first_name` to get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I made it so

```
 truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'created_date')
    qs = Profile.objects.extra({'date': truncate_date})
    report = qs.values('user_report__stat_report__name', 'date').filter(
        id=profiles_id).annotate(Sum('user_report__stat_report__value'))
```

Thank's